# How to make password protected posts that will expire after they are used?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there a possible way to make password protected posts that will expire after they are used?

Comment: When you say used do you mean viewed or by a certain date?

Comment: Yes if the post already viewed using the given password.

Comment: I will have to set the password to be expired.

Comment: so do you want the change the password, so that the post is not accessible with the used password anymore, or do you want to hide/delete the post completely?

Comment: Not really want to change the password, I just wanna set the password to be expired after the post being viewed using the given password so that the post will not be accessible with the used password anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 add_filter( 'post_password_expires',           'my_cookie_time' );


   function my_cookie_time( $time ) {


return 600; // 600 = 10 minutes. Use 0 to expire the cookie at the end of the current browsing session.


   }
```